# How to represent a sine function in the statevector $|\psi\rangle = sin(kx)$

Tags: quantum-gate, unitarity

Is there a quantum circuit that encodes the statevector so that the coefficients of the statevector $|\psi\rangle$ corresponds to a **discrete** representation of $sin(kx)$ in $[0,1]$?
In particular, I'd like to have a set of gates that scales and works for all qubit number $n$. I'd be happy with $sin(x)$ but ideally, I'm looking for higher frequencies multiples as well.

By statevector I am referring to the set of probabilities $(\psi_1,\psi_2,...,\psi_N)$ associated with $|00...0\rangle$, $|00...1\rangle$,...,$|11...1\rangle$ that one gets when reading the output. Please note that I am thinking in the framework of variational algorithms. In these cases, given a qubit register $|\textbf{q}\rangle=|q_1\rangle \otimes ... \otimes |q_n\rangle$, we encode vectors as
\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \psi_k |\text{binary(k)}\rangle
\end{equation}

It is this vector in particular whose entries $\psi_i$ I want to encode to represent a sine. For example, for 3 qubits this vector will have $N=8$ entries. If you divide [0,1] uniformly in $[x_0, ...,x_{N-1}]$, I am looking for an unitary such that $\psi_i=sin(x_i)$. (Or I guess would be more correct to say $sin(2\pi x_i)$)

If possible, I'm looking for both theoretical explanation and *practical* circuit implementation that I could run and test (not just "theoretically there is an oracle..." etc.). Also, among the possible set of unitaries, clearly the shallower and less connected, the better.

If the question isn't clear please ask for clarification in the comments - I'll be happy to improve it.

Comment: So you're effectively after something that's the imaginary component of a state $U_{QFT}|0\rangle$, from the quantum Fourier transform?

Comment: No, as far as I understood when computing QFT your outputs are the projection along the $sin(kx)$ basis, whereas here I would like to assemble a state vector whose coefficients are a discrete representation of a sine function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth noting that the Fourier transform implements
$$
|\Psi\rangle=U_{QFT}|0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1}e^{2\pi i\frac{j}{2^n}}|j\rangle,
$$
so for some particular choice of frequency, what you're effectively asking for is, up to normalisation,
$$
\text{Im}(|\Psi\rangle).
$$

Now, there's a neat way to do this. There's a standard proof that demonstrates that only-real-amplitude quantum computation is just as powerful as quantum computation (see definition 1 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301040)) - you add a single ancilla qubit whose 0/1 value represents whether the amplitude is real or imaginary. So, if you implement the quantum Fourier transform using this circuit construction, and you measure that ancilla qubit, if you find it to be in the $|1\rangle$ state, you've created exactly the state you want. I believe this happens with probability $1/2$, so repeat until success is a very reasonable strategy. Alternatively, you could apply amplitude amplification, but that will make your circuit much more complicated.

If you want different frequencies (within limits), just choose a different number of qubits to use! You can also vary which basis element the input state is.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Correct me if I am wrong, but when you apply a QFT, aren't the entry of $\psi$ the coefficient associated with the amplitude of each frequency? I am looking for something a bit different. I'll expand the question with more context

Comment: Is it really the probabilities you're after rather than the amplitudes?

Comment: Sorry If I haven't edited the question yet but I'm trying to understand how to write it down. First of all, I am working in the framework of variational algorithms and not binary calculus like HHL etc. In these algorithms, the way you encode a vector is in the probabilities associated with each output. There is a certain probability you get the 0 vector as an output, and this is the first entry of the vector I am looking for and so on for the others. I'll add this edit to the question and as soon as I can expand even further

Comment: I've updated it, you might want to check if it's now more clear

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what my answer covers (incidentally, the $\psi_k$ are *probability amplitudes*, not probabilities).

Comment: You are right!  Just two clarifications: 1) In standard QFT you have one ancillary qubit that is the one that controls the $\pi/n$ Rotations. Is it that ancilla, in particular, I have to measure to get the imaginary part, or do I need an additional ancillary qubit?
2) Based on the trials I have done in qiskit changing the number of qubits does not change the frequency of the sine that you get when you apply QFTto the 0 vector. Rather, its discrete representation becomes more accurate. I guess to get different frequencies one must change the $|0\rangle$ that is now input to QFT, but how?

Comment: You can create any frequency $2\pi j/2^t$ by using $t$ qubits and an initial state $|\text{binary}(j)\rangle$.

Comment: standard QFT does not have an ancilla. Are you thinking about the phase estimation protocol?

Comment: I'm using this as a reference for QFT https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/quantum-fourier-transform.html
Maybe it was improper on my side to call the 0th qubit ancilla since it's probably not ancillary but there all controlled rotation have their control on the first qubit. I guess then I have to add an additional ancilla to make sure I am measuring $\text{Im}(|\psi\rangle)$, right? If so, do all the gate in the QFT need an additional control on that ancilla?

Comment: By the way, I am trying to control the frequency as you suggested by selecting a $|\text{binary}(j)\rangle$, for instance flipping all qubits yields $j=2^n-1$. However, it looks like I always get a superposition in the output state of the like $\sin(2\pi x)*\sin(2\pi j/2^t)$. Basically, the amplitude of the sine of the frequency I selected is sinusoidal itself.

Comment: Hi, do you think you could answer this last point so that I can accept your answer? That would be great so we can have a complete answer for future readers as well

Comment: I don't know how to answer you because I don't think you should be getting that! (what's $x$ for a start?) For detailed support on your implementation, you should probably ask a separate question and provide details of exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you. I'll post the link here in the comment as well once I publish it